# My code won't download Excel or CSV files, other file types work OK

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to download excel and csv file in android through webview.

Other File types are downloading.

Everytime i try to download the file(excel,csv) the app stop responding.

Here is My Code

```
 public static void download(Activity mActivity, String url, String contentDisposition, String mimetype) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
```

> To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded

```
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.downloading, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
```

> Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this in your code and set the extension you are downloading through the Webview

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String newString ="THE FILE NAME.mp3"
        Log.i(ERROR, "this is it " + newString);
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath();
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(folder, newString);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Hope This could Help you.